# Is the use of @ directing my comments?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-bydesign

I've posted a few comments in response to other users and tried to use the @ notation to direct my comment to a specific user. This works on other stackexchange sites but I'm wondering if it works here in computational science?

For example if I write "@joe blah blah blah", then post the comment, it only shows up on the board as "blah blah blah" and is missing the "@joe", which makes me wonder if joe is getting my message?

Comment: Really? That's worked in the past.

Comment: I think it only works if you completely write out the entire name without spaces, @ThatsRightJack.

Comment: /cc @GeoffOxberry see also [Don't remove the @ part of my comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97283/310919).

Answer (score 5):

The owner of the post you are commenting to always gets notified of comments. `@`-notifications to him/her are not necessary, and SE chose to remove them automatically.